# wordpress show random post that hasn't been shown earlier

Tags: php, wordpress

I created this really simple function following the documentary of WordPress and as I understood it, this code should be working just fine

```
query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'post__not_in' => $_SESSION['watched'], 'showposts' => 1));
```

and the code for the session is no more advanced then this

```
if(!in_array($post->ID, $_SESSION['watched'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['watched'],$post->ID);
}
```

If you know of any other solution or how to fix this specific one 
all answers are very much appreciated... If I missed something out just tell me and I'll add that information.

Comment: What is the question? Is the code not working as expected or are you wondering if there is a different / better / more common solution?

Comment: yes its not working, im able to see the same post over and over again

Comment: Are you starting your session properly using `session_start();`? — http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: yes ofc ive even printed it out to se if everything was getting set

Comment: What version of wordpress are you using? If you get rid of `orderby` does the query work?

Comment: I use version 3.0.5 and yes it works but it doesnt show random posts and i can still see the same post over and over again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This topic on wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/excluding-page-ids-using-post_not_in) seems relevant to your question - there are obviously some rather weird issues with `post__not_in`.

Try this:

```
function removeSeenPosts ($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (count($_SESSION['watched']) > 0) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID NOT IN(' . implode (',', $_SESSION['watched']) . ') ';
    }
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'removeSeenPosts');
query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1));
remove_filter('posts_where', 'removeSeenPosts');
```

If that doesn't help (which I actually suspect), the problem is clearly related to the post ids' storage in the session.

Two things come to mind:

- Can `$_SESSION` be populated after anything but headers has been sent? I don't remember …
- Storing the posts in a proper cookie seems like a viable alternative and would, as an added bonus, make the storage persistent across sessions.

Untested implementation as a plugin:

```
function setViewedPostCookies() {
    if (is_single())
    {
        global $wp_query;
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['watched']))
        {
            $excluded_posts = array();
        }
        else
        {
            $excluded_posts = implode(',', $_COOKIE['watched']);
        }
        $excluded_posts[] = $wp_query->post->ID;
        $excluded_posts = array_unique($excluded_posts);
        setcookie('watched', explode(',', $excluded_posts), time() + 3600000, '/');
    }
}

add_action( 'get_header', 'setViewedPostCookies' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't work with `$_SESSION['watched']` array because `$_SESSION` variable not linked to the MySQL table and as result formatted query didn't know how many posts it should return.

I see only one solution to solve this task correctly:

You need to create one more table in database that can store `session_id` and `post_id` variables. For example we name this table `wp_watched`.

For example structure of our table will be:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_watched (
    `watched_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `watched_SID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `watched_POST_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`watched_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And data will store on our table like this:

```
`watched_ID` |           `watched_SID`          | `watched_POST_ID`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 | 345 
2            | 88578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4 | 123
3            | 1a36591bceec49c832079e270d7e8b73 | 5
4            | 2b1d3a6249c2d223c620393fa6420868 | 98
5            | 793560d7e4ef27db84dfe776fed9cea5 | 12
...
```

Then your code for session you need to rewrite for something like this, using [custom queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries):

```
$watchedrows = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT watched_ID FROM wp_watched WHERE watched_SID = " . session_id() . " AND watched_POST_ID = " . $post->ID);
if(!$watchedrows->watched_ID) {
    $wpdb->insert('wp_watched', array('watched_SID' => session_id(), 'watched_POST_ID' => $post->ID), array('%s', '%d'));
}
```

Then you need to create your own [custom query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) to get posts based on connection between `wp_posts` table and `wp_watched` table:

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT 
        $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM 
        $wpdb->posts, 
        wp_watched
    WHERE 
        $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
        AND wp_watched.watched_SID = " . session_id() . "
        AND $wpdb->posts.ID != wp_watched.watched_POST_ID
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1";
$randompost = $wpdb->get_row($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Then if everything is ok variable `$randompost` will contain your random post.

Not sure if code I provide works, I didn't test it. Maybe some SQL selects need to be rewritten.

Just to show you direction where you need to go.

Comment: Frankly, how is the variable "not linked"!? It's being passed in there.

Comment: … not even talking about the fact that you're storing an awful lot of session information in a DB without ever cleaning it up.